# Shortly loosing connection with websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I've been trying to connect to a websocket on my api and i've managed to do it very briefly before having the connection lost.
The client code (script on html):

```js
        const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:1337')
        ws.addEventListener('open', (event) => {
            ws.send(JSON.stringify({title: 'like that', message: 'gimme update'}));
        })

        ws.addEventListener('close', (close) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(close))
        })
        ws.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
            const dataFromServer = JSON.parse(event.data);
            console.log('Message from server', JSON.parse(event.data))
            const h1 = document.getElementById('changeHere');
            h1.innerText = `Changing: ${dataFromServer.statusId}`
        })
```

and my backend code:

```js
...
const websocket = new WebSocket.Server({ server: httpServer });

const TAG_WEBSOCKET = '[WEBSOCKET]';

websocket.on('connection', (connection) => {
  connection.on('error', (err) => console.error);
  logger.info('client connected');
  connection.send('message');
  emitter.on('updateStatus', (data) => {
    logger.info(TAG_WEBSOCKET + 'Update status for ' + data.id);
    connection.send(JSON.stringify(data));
  });
  connection.on('close', () => {
    logger.info('connection closed');
    emitter.removeAllListeners();
  });
});

httpServer.listen(PORT, () => {
    logger.info(`${TAG} Server running on port: ${PORT}`);
  });
```

and when trying to connect I only get this
frontend (client):
[image]

and in the backend:

```bash
2023-01-04 21:28:44 [info] client connected
info: Client disconnect: undefined
error: Can not find client undefined on disconnect
2023-01-04 21:28:44 [info] connection closed
```

How can I make the connection work as long as the client is connected ? Does it have anything to do with the fact that the API is largely used by other clients(not websockets) and this might interfere ? Should I have one API dedicated to the websocket business logic ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "the API is largely used by other clients (not websockets)?  What you show here is entirely webSocket code.  There is no other way to access this code except via a webSocket connection.

Comment: Which server-side webSocket library are you using?

Comment: The library both on backend and frontend is the ws. I mean that there are routes being used and there's talso the websocket inside the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your client code looks wrong to me.  You have this:

```
    ws.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
        const dataFromServer = JSON.parse(event.data);
        console.log('Message from server', JSON.parse(event.data))
        const h1 = document.getElementById('changeHere');
        h1.innerText = `Changing: ${dataFromServer.statusId}`
    })
```

This assumes that what gets passed to the event listener is a Javascript object that always has a `.data` property and that's where the data is that you sent.

But, that's not what the doc for the `ws` library shows.  It shows this client code where you are just directly getting the data that was sent (no Javascript object with properties):

```
ws.on('message', function message(data) {
  console.log('received: %s', data);
});
```

Which matches up with something like this on the server:

```
ws.send('something');
```

So, when you do this in your server:

```
connection.send('message');
```

That won't match up with your client code that tries to do:

```
const dataFromServer = JSON.parse(event.data);
```

---

FYI, I'd suggest a couple things for debugging stuff like this:

1. Put a unique `console.log()` message at the start of each of your event handlers so you can track the message flow precisely.
2. Make sure you have `try/catch` handlers with their own `console.log()` indicators anywhere you could throw (particularly `JSON.parse()`).
3. Make sure you have 'error' event handlers, everywhere they could be (with logging).